# Why does jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser).asText() return an empty String for me?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, post

I wrote an REST service to ingest metadata from post requests. I am using spring-data-elasticsearch, and I made a custom Metadata Object to deserialize Json into that looks like this:

```
@Document(indexName = "metadata_v1", type = "metadata")
    public class Metadata {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String uuid;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String userId;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date_time)
    private Date date = null;
    @Field(type = FieldType.String)
    private String classification;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<NumericKeyValue> numericKeyValue;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<TextKeyValue> textKeyValue;
```

with a bunch of getters and setters.

It works fine for all of its fields except `numericKeyValue` and `textKeyValue` Json Arrays. I couldn't send those in via post request, and realized I needed to write a deserializer. I did that for `numericKeyValue`, and as far as I've read, it's supposed to look like this:

```
public class NumericKeyValueJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<NumericKeyValue>>{

    @Override
    public List<NumericKeyValue> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        TypeReference<List<NumericKeyValue>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<NumericKeyValue>>(){};
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String numericKeyValue = root.get("numericKeyValue").asText();
        return mapper.readValue( numericKeyValue, typeRef);
    }

}
```

And I added

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = NumericKeyValueJsonDeserializer.class)
```

to the field declaration in my Metadata class.

However, after a lot of testing, I have come to realize that the JsonNode `root` not only doesn't contain `"numericKeyValue"`, but gives me a completely empty string when I invoke `root.asText()`.

I have been using Postman to send in a post request to my endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value="/metadata_v1/ingest", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
public @ResponseBody Metadata createEntry(@RequestBody Metadata entry){
    repository.save(entry);
    return entry;
}
```

containing the following Json:

```
{
    "numericKeyValue": 
    [
      {
        "key": "velocity",
        "value": 55.5
      },
      {
        "key": "angle",
        "value": 90
      }
    ]
}
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
"numericKeyValue" : {
    "type" : "nested",
    "properties" : {
        "key" : {"type" : "string"},
        "value" : {"type" : "double"}
    }
}
```

I can show more things if needed. I think I will be fine if I can just get the JSON I send in Java somehow, perhaps as a String. I've been getting empty Strings that result in null pointer exceptions and when I tried `String numericKeyValue = jp.getText()` the String was just the current token of "[", which I guess at least isn't an empty String, but still doesn't help me.

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the value for `numericKeyValue` is an array. You should replace the following line:

```
String numericKeyValue = root.get("numericKeyValue").asText();
```

with:

```
if ( root.isArray() ){
    // loop trough array
    for (final JsonNode node : root){
       String numericKeyValue = node.get("numericKeyValue").asText();
       // then build the list to be returned
    }
}
```